# STM32L072CZTx mpu6050 i2c No ACK after some successfull transmitting

Tags: embedded, stm32, i2c, hal, mpu6050

i made a customboard with a MPU-6050 & STM32L072CZTx on it.
My problem is, that the MPU-6050 doesn't ack after some successfull transmision.

I have two 4,7k pull-ups on SCL and SDA.
Restarting the MCU doesn't fix it.
I have to unplug the power to get the MPU to ACK again for some transmision.

I am using STM32 HAL and added 2 images for clarification.

What i tried:

- Replaced MPU6050
- lowered I2C frequenzy
- much more...

Thanks for your help.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef writeBytes(uint8_t deviceAdd, uint8_t regAdd, uint8_t *data, uint8_t size)
{
  uint8_t buffer[size + 1];
  buffer[0] = regAdd;
  memcpy((buffer + 1), data, size);
  return HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, deviceAdd << 1, buffer, size + 1, I2C_TIMEOUT);           
}
HAL_StatusTypeDef readBytes(uint8_t deviceAdd, uint8_t regAdd, uint8_t *data, uint8_t size)
{
  return HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(deviceAdd << 1), (uint16_t)regAdd, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, size, I2C_TIMEOUT);
}
```

[Oscilloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENerI.png)

[MPU6050 schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8fsN.png)

Comment: Does `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`returns after the transmission is finished (or I2C fifo is filled) ? If the function is only storing the buffer for transmitting later (after IRQ or whatever), since `buffer`is a local variable it would mess up the transmission

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit returns after the transmission is finished.